# java ThreadPoolExecutor default

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, executor, queueing

I was reading Oracles documentation on [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and in particular about the queuing in case there are more requests than Threads available. However I did not find out what the default settings are.

To instantiate the Executor the only thing I do is:

```
executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
```

where executor is from java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService and Executor is the one given by java.util.concurrent.Executors.

From there on the only line where the executor appears again is in:

```
executor.execute(worker);
```

So as you see, I never set any property about the queue type or size the executor is using.

What I want to know is which of the strategies described in the documentation I linked is being used.

With the implementation as I've shown: Am I using an unbounded queue? Is it bounded? If so what's the default size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29):

> public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)
>
> Creates a thread pool that reuses a **fixed number of threads** operating off a shared **unbounded queue**. At any point, at most nThreads threads will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available.

(emphasis mine)

If you want maximum flexibility, you can use the ThreadPoolExecutor constructor, which will let you choose every detail you want.

Answer (score 0):

See Executors src

```
public static ExecutorService  newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
         return new ThreadPoolExecutor (nThreads, nThreads,
                                       0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                       new LinkedBlockingQueue <Runnable >());
}
```

as we can see it is unbounded LinkedBlockingQueue